# Why is my devtools missing the has_devel() function?

Tags: r

I am trying to follow [Hadley Wickham's guide to create packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/intro.html), but I am getting errors after following his steps exactly. I know many others have been able to do so without error, so I am unsure how to proceed.

Here are my inputs and outputs so far:

```
> install.packages(c("devtools", "roxygen2", "testthat", "knitr"))
Installing packages into ‘C:/Users/jerem/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’ 
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘git2r’

trying URL     'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/git2r_0.19.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 3026420 bytes (2.9 MB)
downloaded 2.9 MB

trying URL     'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/devtools_1.13.3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 443739 bytes (433 KB)
downloaded 433 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/roxygen2_6.0.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 756869 bytes (739 KB)
downloaded 739 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/testthat_1.0.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1057803 bytes (1.0 MB)
downloaded 1.0 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/knitr_1.17.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1027379 bytes (1003 KB)
downloaded 1003 KB

package ‘git2r’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘devtools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘roxygen2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘testthat’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘knitr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\jerem\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpeuw2OQ\downloaded_packages


> install.packages("rstudioapi")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/jerem/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/rstudioapi_0.7.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 129765 bytes (126 KB)
downloaded 126 KB

package ‘rstudioapi’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\jerem\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpeuw2OQ\downloaded_packages
> rstudioapi::isAvailable("0.99.149")
[1] TRUE
> devtools::install_github("hadley/devtools")
Downloading GitHub repo hadley/devtools@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/hadley/devtools/zipball/master
Installing devtools
Downloading GitHub repo rstudio/rstudioapi@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/rstudio/rstudioapi/zipball/master
Installing rstudioapi
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:/Users/jerem/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpeuw2OQ/devtools9c45cf312b/rstudio-rstudioapi-8e8bfb0"  \
  --library="C:/Users/jerem/Documents/R/win-library/3.4" --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'rstudioapi' ...
** R
** tests
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386
*** arch - x64
* DONE (rstudioapi)
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.1/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:/Users/jerem/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpeuw2OQ/devtools9c42002296c/hadley-devtools-a0c8d73"  \
  --library="C:/Users/jerem/Documents/R/win-library/3.4" --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'devtools' ...
** R
** inst
** tests
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386
*** arch - x64
* DONE (devtools)
```

Everything seems to be going well up to this point, but breaks down here.

```
> library(devtools)
Loading required package: usethis
> has_devel()
Error in has_devel() : could not find function "has_devel"
```

Additional info:

My path:

> > Sys.getenv("PATH")

```
[1] "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.4.1\\bin\\x64;c:\\Rtools\\bin;c:\\Rtools\\mingw_32\\bin;C:\\ProgramData\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32;C:\\WINDOWS;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Users\\jerem\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;"
```

Contents of devtools:

> ls(pos = "package:devtools")

[1](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/intro.html) "add_path"                    "as.package"                  "bash"                        "build"
  [5] "build_manual"                "build_vignettes"             "build_win"                   "check"
  [9] "check_built"                 "check_cran"                  "check_dep_version"           "check_failures"
 [13] "check_man"                   "clean_dll"                   "clean_vignettes"             "create"
 [17] "create_description"          "dev_mode"                    "dev_package_deps"            "dev_packages"
 [21] "devtest"                     "document"                    "dr_devtools"                 "dr_github"
 [25] "get_path"                    "github_pat"                  "github_pull"                 "github_release"
 [29] "has_tests"                   "install"                     "install_bioc"                "install_bitbucket"
 [33] "install_cran"                "install_deps"                "install_dev_deps"            "install_git"
 [37] "install_github"              "install_local"               "install_svn"                 "install_url"
 [41] "install_version"             "is.package"                  "lint"                        "load_all"
 [45] "loaded_packages"             "missing_s3"                  "on_path"                     "package_deps"
 [49] "package_file"                "parse_deps"                  "r_env_vars"                  "release"
 [53] "release_checks"              "reload"                      "revdep"                      "revdep_check"
 [57] "revdep_check_print_problems" "revdep_check_reset"          "revdep_check_resume"         "revdep_check_save_summary"
 [61] "revdep_email"                "revdep_maintainers"          "rhub_check"                  "run_examples"
 [65] "session_info"                "set_path"                    "setup"                       "show_news"
 [69] "source_gist"                 "source_url"                  "spell_check"                 "submit_cran"
 [73] "system_check"                "system_output"               "test"                        "uninstall"
 [77] "unload"                      "update_packages"             "use_appveyor"                "use_build_ignore"
 [81] "use_code_of_conduct"         "use_coverage"                "use_cran_badge"              "use_cran_comments"
 [85] "use_data"                    "use_data_raw"                "use_dev_version"             "use_git"
 [89] "use_git_hook"                "use_github"                  "use_github_links"            "use_gpl3_license"
 [93] "use_mit_license"             "use_news_md"                 "use_package"                 "use_package_doc"
 [97] "use_rcpp"                    "use_readme_md"               "use_readme_rmd"              "use_revdep"
[101] "use_rstudio"                 "use_test"                    "use_testthat"                "use_travis"
[105] "use_vignette"                "uses_testthat"               "wd"                          "with_debug"

What should I be changing so that I can use the has_devel function?

Comment: I had the same problem. See https://github.com/hadley/devtools/issues/1219 and run `find_rtools()` first.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `dev_tools` by running the RStudio with administrator rights.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact issue. has_devel() and find_rtools() just didn't seem to be in the devtools package I had installed.

So instead of installing from github like in Hadley's instructions:

```
devtools::install_github("hadley/devtools")
```

I installed devtools from CRAN using:

```
install.packages("devtools")
```

After that both

```
devtools::find_rtools()
```

and

```
devtools::has_devel()
```

ran successfully